# C++ cannot convert 'const char*' to 'std::string*'

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have this code below and I'm getting the error upon compilation:

`error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'std::string*' for argument '1' to 'void sillyFunction(std::string*, int)'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int counter = 0;

void sillyFunction(string * str, int cool=0);

int main(){
    sillyFunction("Cool");
    sillyFunction("Cooler", 1);
    return 0;
}

void sillyFunction(string * str, int cool){
    counter++;
    if (cool){
        for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) cout << *str << endl;
    } else {
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't take your parameter in as a `string *` try just using a `const string &` instead

EDIT:

`std::string` and `const char*` are different types.  the `std::string` already has a conversion from string literals (ex: `"Cool"`) to the actual string object.  So by passing in the string literal `"Cool"` you are in a sense passing in a `std::string` object, not a pointer to one.

The reason I chose to use a `const string &` is mostly from personal coding practices.  This minimizes stack memory usage, and since you are passing in a constant string literal, there is no need for the parameter to be modify-able.

Also don't forget if you change from a `string *` that you no longer need to dereference it in your `cout`:

```
if (cool){
    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) cout << str << endl;
} else {
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you elaborate your answer and explain why he should do this I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
void sillyFunction(string * str, int cool){
   counter++;
    if (cool){
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) cout << *str << endl;
    } else {
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
}
```

to

```
void sillyFunction(const char* str, int cool){
    counter++;
    if (cool){
        for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++) cout << str << endl;
    } else {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To explain what the problem actually *is*...

While the compiler will happily arrange for a `char *`/C-string to be "converted" to a `std::string` via the appropriate `std::string` constructor, that's not what you've asked for.

You have asked for a *pointer* to an *existing* `std::string` object. By definition, what is passed to your function must be the address of an **already existing** `std::string` (or descendant) object.

You must understand pointers as a distinct type -- your function takes a `pointer-to-std::string` "object". While a `std::string` can be accessed via a pointer to `std::string`, the pointer itself is *not* a `std::string`, nor can it be "converted" to a `std::string`, nor can it be treated as a pointer-to-char (or vice-versa).

The easiest alternative is indeed a const reference to a `std::string` (`const std::string &`). const, in this case, because you're not doing anything to modify the string. If you were, that would be a different matter, and you'd have to consider carefully whether you intend for the caller to see your changes.

By doing this, you're saying you want a `std::string` object (remember, a reference to an object *is that object*, see [C++ FAQ 8.5](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.5) in particular), which allows the compiler to invoke the appropriate constructor to create a std::string for you when the function is called with a `char *` (const or not).

At the same time, if someone passes you an *actual* `std::string`, the constructor is avoided and you get the same efficiency as if you had taken a `pointer-to-std::string`. Win-win.

Alternatively, of course, you can just take a plain `std::string`, but in that case you *always* get a copy of the string being passed in, whether it's a C-string or a `std::string`. Sometimes that's desirable, sometimes not. In your case, you don't do anything but print the string out, making the overhead unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive that by changing the prototype to:

```
void sillyFunction(string const &str, int cool=0);
```

`char const *` could be implicitly converted to a temporary `std::string`, which in turn could be passed by reference (`std::string const &`).  There's no implicit conversion to a pointer (`std::string *`), that's why you get the error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const string &str`?

Comment: @ultimatebuster, it's the same.  It's just a matter of taste how to write that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from a `const char *` to a `string`, but not to a `string *`.

Perhaps you want your `sillyFunction` to take a const reference?

```
void sillyFunction(const string &str, int cool){
    counter++;
    if (cool){
        for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) cout << str << endl;
    } else {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
void sillyFunction(const string& str, int cool=0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use pointers for your functions you have to declare the strings somewhere.  memory needs to be allocated.  so either declare a variable or call new to create memory for the string.

```
int main(){
    string str = "Cool";
    string str2 = "Cooler";
    sillyFunction(&str);
    sillyFunction(&str2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution for that, using string copy

char s[20]
strcpy(s,const char *p);

Then you have the string pointed by *p in s...
it works..